# Active_admin + Composite_primary_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, composite-primary-key

I'm using the composite primary keys gem and active_admin and I've got a problem with index page.
Can I customize the index.html.arb file somehow? Or change the belongs_to association?

My model:

```
 class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.table_name = "vehicle"
 self.primary_key = "vehicle_id"
 belongs_to :operator, :foreign_key => :operator_id
 **belongs_to :orgunit, :foreign_key => [:operator_id, :run_code]**
```

---

app/admin/vehicles.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Vehicle do
  index do
  id_column
  column  :version
  column  :description
  default_actions
```

end

---

index page error:

```
NoMethodError in Admin/vehicles#index
Showing /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/activeadmin-
0.5.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `to_sym' for [:operator_id, :run_code]:Array
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe active_admin does not accept composite keys. =/ (Rails either)

Anyway, look into this link below, it may help you, and explain why active_admin query all belongs_to associations in Index page.

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Preventing-Extra-Queries-on-Index-Pages

Comment: Sorry I'm late
https://github.com/codereading/active_admin/wiki/Preventing-Extra-Queries-on-Index-Pages